# PHP/MySQL search for result in string using variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql-like

I have a query that just isn't providing results:

```
$name = "John Smith";

$query = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE lname LIKE '%$name%' AND fname LIKE '%$name%'";
```

lname in the database would be listed as Smith
fname in the database would POSSIBLY be listed as John S.

Some entries have a middle initial attached to their name, some don't.

Also, names are pulled in as one string on the page where I am querying this information, not first name and last name strings. Limitation of the existing code.

So I'm trying to search for the last name in the string $name as well as the first name. I assume I'm doing it wrong. Is this possible? Or is there another way to do this?

Comment: `echo $query;` and run it in MySQL directly.

Comment: You're searching for the string `John Smith` in both the `lname` and `fname` fields - that's not going to find anything, as the contents are split over both fields.

Comment: $query = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE lname LIKE '%$name%' OR fname LIKE '%$name%'";

Comment: What if I have Dan Smith and John Walters though? I need to make sure that the string John Smith, either first or last name appears in both lname and fname.

Comment: Which version of mysql do you use?

Comment: What I need to do is to see if any part of lname exists in $name and any part of fname exists in $name. And no, $name cannot be broken up into two variables. That would make this much easier.

Comment: @MarioMueller MySQL 5.0.96 I think.

Comment: Then my regex comment below should work ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this (if I'm understanding you correctly):

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE '$name' like concat(fname,' %')
  AND '$name' like concat('% ',lname)
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8bb87/2)

To search the fname field, it concats a ' %' after the fullname being searched.  And to search the lname field, it concats a '% ' before the fullname.

*EDIT: A slight variation of Mario's good comment that uses `REGEXP`:*

```
SELECT *, CONCAT_WS(' ', fname, lname)
FROM my_table
WHERE  CONCAT_WS(' ', fname, lname) REGEXP REPLACE('$name',' ', '.*')
```

[More Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8bb87/6)

Since you mention you cannot break up the parameter (why?), this uses replace to replace the space accordingly.

Comment: I would modify this a bit: select * from foo2 where "john smith" in (fname, lname) or CONCAT_WS(" ", fname, lname) REGEXP "john.*smith";

Comment: @MarioMueller -- I like the REGEXP option -- I'll edit the post to show.  Thanks!

Comment: @MarioMueller -- actually, that would require altering the input of $name and I didn't think OP could do that.  If OP can alter input, then I like this option too.

Comment: Yes, you're right. This might be no acceptable due the presented immutability of the original value, but I might be worth a try ;)

Comment: @MarioMueller -- I updated with a version that should work using SQL to replace the input.  Up to OP at this point :)  Thanks!

Comment: I accepted the REGEXP. It works. I'm happy with it. Not sure if it's the best in terms of performance, but it works nicely.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what is exactly the problem but the next query could help you:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE '$name' LIKE CONCAT('%', lname ,'%') and '$name' LIKE         CONCAT('%',fname ,'%')
```

If you need to check if lname is contained in $name the query you show is incorrectly and you are checking the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

i have the solution for it.. you can try like this

```
$name = "John Smith";

$query = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE fname LIKE substring_index(".$name.",' ',1) AND fname LIKE substring_index(".$name.",' ',-1)";
```